# Eager loading doesn't work for many to one Laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a One to Many relationship between two classes. When I try to receive the belongsTo child via eager loading, it doesn't work for some odd reason. According to the following it should work: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Te tables have the following columns, among others (legacy made, no option to change this). `kasticket_.kassa_id` and `kassa.code` refer to each other:

```
kasticket_.ticketnr, kasticket_.kassa_id, ...
kassa.code, ...
```

Here are the classes, somewhat simplified.
ReceiptDetail:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Pos;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReceiptDetail extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'kasticket_';

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'ticketnr';

    /**
     * Get pos.
     */
    public function pos()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pos::class, 'kassa_id', 'code');
    }
}
```

Pos:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\ReceiptDetail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pos extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'kassa';

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'code';

    /**
     * Get the receipt details.
     */
    public function receiptDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ReceiptDetail::class, 'kassa_id', 'code');
    }
}
```

This gives null as a result, rather than the Pos model. In the query log I can see it gets eager loaded however:

```
$receipts = \App\ReceiptDetail::with('pos')->get();
foreach ($receipts as $receipt) {
    dd($receipt->pos);
}
```

This gives me the expected Pos model, but an extra DB request has been made:

```
$receipts = \App\ReceiptDetail::with('pos')->get();
foreach ($receipts as $receipt) {
    dd($receipt->pos()->first());
}
```

From the query log I see the following:

```
select * from `kasticket`
select * from `kassa` where `kassa`.`code` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: ReceiptDetail has one pos() record right?

Comment: `ReceiptDetail` table must have `pos_id` according to how you've setup this relation. Instead of `dd` use `dump` and see the result for all `$receipts` you are selecting. Maybe the first one really has `pos_id` as null.

Comment: @DsRaj, that is correct

Comment: @RubenColpaert add the table schema in your question

Comment: I added some information. Working with legacy tables, which makes it kinda ugly, but this should help I think.

Answer (score 0):

The unique identifiers of the tables (`kasticket_.kassa_id` and `kassa.code`) are strings in the DB. I had to add the following line the the Pos class:

```
/**
 * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't follow the proper name in primary key and foreign key then you need to add the relationship properly

Change like this:

```
public function pos()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Pos::class,'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

**POS Model**

```
public function receiptDetails()
{
   return $this->hasMany(ReceiptDetail::class,'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

[More info](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: This is the case, the query log gives the expected result. Also, I tried changing places, just to be sure, but that only gives me expected errors, since Laravel looks for non existing columns.

Comment: It is all in the original post. Unless I am missing something?